# Maximum capacity TEXT dataType in WebSQL

Tags: database, memory, text, web-sql

I'm developing a Web Application, but I have a question,
What is the maximum TEXT DataType Capacity in WebSQL?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TINYTEXT    256 bytes

TEXT            65,535 bytes            ~64kb

MEDIUMTEXT  16,777,215 bytes    ~16MB

LONGTEXT    4,294,967,295 bytes     ~4GB